# Email Verification URL in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

how can I use given URL for email varfication in ASP.NET WEB API?

var Email="test@test.com"
var key="122";

"http://localhost:50740/api/Users/VerifyEmail/" + Email + "/" + key

when i enter into web browser, debug it

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage VerifyEmail(string email, string verificationKey)
{
}
   paramters of action method are always null.
```

in Global.asax.cs i have defined following route

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "EmailVerification",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{email}/{verificationKey}",
                defaults: new { action = "VerifyEmail", email = "", verificationKey = "" }
             );
```

basically, I want verification email to be handled which has two parameters   email and key.

your response will be appreciated.

Comment: I used your code exactly, and it worked fine for me. Is there a greedier route that is overriding the one you are mapping above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by moving the custom route to the top where routes are defined.